# SVN update after relocate fails with "no such revision" message

Tags: svn, version-control

We used to have a shared SVN repository for several projects and yesterday, our SVN admin created a new SVN repository specific to our project.

I relocated my existing checkout of the project to the new SVN repository but now, when I make a SVN update, I get an error message like `"No such revision 223297".`

Indeed, the new repository has only the number of revisions specific to our project (around `33000` commits) while the old one had `223400`.

I would like to know if it's possible to switch all my existing checked out folders to the new repository? Otherwise, I will have to do some clean checkouts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously your admin failed to include padding revisions which usually is highly recommended when using svndumpfilter to split repositories.

Otherwise it is absolute impossible to update your working copy with your repository, as SVN orients itself on revision numbers and your repository is (technical speaking) a different repository(usually the UUID of the repository should not match as well.. another quirk which should be fixed by your admin). Also if you use external tools like bugtracker which are saving the revision numbers to link contents to your sourcecode, these references are lost as well.

The best solution would be to redo the repository creation without  svndumpfilter switch --**drop-empty-revs** however, then your work in your new repository is lost..

Comment: The admin doesn't want to create a repository without **--drop-empty-revs** switch. Every revision take at least 8k and he doesn't want to have a huge SVN dump. That means that we are good for doing clean checkouts now...

Answer (score 11):

1. Back up the working directory
2. Delete the .svn directory under the top working directory
3. Check out the entire working directory.

Worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have to do some clean checkouts.

In my situation, our SVN admin created a new SVN repository clone fully from the old repository. And I got the same message when I updated my working copy after relocated it to the new SVN repository.

Then I found out that's because I did a SVN update before I relocate to the new repository, and the revision number is just beyond the revision number in the new repository.

So, here is my solution:

1. relocate back to the **old repository**
2. Use `Update to revision...` to update to your working copy to an older version(just **the version before your SVN admin create the new repository**)
3. relocate to the **new repository**, and now try to do a SVN update again :)

Hope this help you.